# strange realloc behavior odd/even netbeans

Tags: c, netbeans, realloc

I have a prime number generator, which generates `unsigned int count` prime numbers and stores them in a dynamically allocated array declared globally `numList globalPrimes` numList is just `typedef unsigned int *numList`. If the value of count is 0, it is ignored and it calculates prime numbers until the value of the previously calulated prime number surpasses `unsigned int until` which is ignored unless count is 0.

```
numList getPrimes(unsigned int count, unsigned int until)
{
    unsigned int i, j;
    unsigned int p = 0;
    char b=1;
    if(globalPrimes==NULL)
    {
        b=0;
        globalPrimes = calloc(count>0? count:until, sizeof(int));
        if(globalPrimes==NULL)
        return NULL;
    }
    globalPrimes[0]=2;   //set first 2 prime #'s in list
    globalPrimes[1]=3;
    for(i=2, p=5; count!=0? (i<count):(globalPrimes[i-1]<=until); p+=2)  //iterate until it finds every prime number. Increments p by 2 starting from the third prime
    {
        if(globalPrimes[i]!=0)  //if the current prime was preordained (a value was set already) skip to the next prime
        {
            p=globalPrimes[i++];
            continue;
        }
        else if(globalPrimes[i]==0)  //if it is 0, allocate the extra memory and find next prime
        {
            if(b)
                globalPrimes=(numList)realloc((void *)globalPrimes, sizeof(int)*((count==0)? (until):(count+1)));
            b=0;
        }

        for(j=0; (p%globalPrimes[j]) && globalPrimes[j]*globalPrimes[j]<p; j++);  //loop through all previous primes until past half of p
        if(p%globalPrimes[j])   //if the prime is still not divisible by the previous prime
            globalPrimes[i++]=p;   // save as the next prime
    }
    globalPrimes[i]=0;
    globalPrimes=(numList)realloc((void *)globalPrimes, (i+(i%2)+1)*sizeof(int));
    return globalPrimes;
}
```

During some tests, I found a weird error. On the penultimate line with `realloc` netBeans (gcc compiler) gives me a "signal" which I assume are like runtime exceptions. The dialogue box reads that the error is SIGABRT, and it aborts the program while not in debugging mode. I have found that this error only occurs when count is an odd number. Even when I modify realloc's arguments so that it always passes even numbers, there is still an error. But when I modify count to only be even at the beginning of the function, it works fine. I can't figure out why this strange details cause this strange behavior.

Comment: [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is your friend.

Comment: What arguments are you passing to `getPrimes`? (I'm testing this)

Comment: Yes, `valgrind` is a debugger that catches exactly these kinds of problems.

Comment: Any odd number that isn't one or negative as the first argument. Zero for the second argument.

Comment: You're code's working fine for me. Do what David says, and use valgrind.

Comment: When I run it in Visual C++, it works fine. I'm guessing it has something to do with using C++ instead. However I believe that Netbeans is to blame

Comment: What's the intent of the `realloc()` call just before the function returns?

Comment: If one were to use the until argument, the number of primes would be undetermined, so I suppose I only need it when count isn't 0. Noted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
globalPrimes[i]=0;
```

just before your last `realloc()` is corrupting memory - it's a write that's just past the end of the array you've allocated.

I think you want to allocate the array like so:

```
globalPrimes = calloc(count>0? (count + 1):until, sizeof(int));
```

So far I've only looked at the case where the function is called with a non-zero `count`; I'm honestly not sure what problems there might be if the function is called with `count == 0` and `until` being some target prime.

Comment: Thank you. I don't even know why I didn't notice that one.

Comment: I tried compiling and running the function under VS 2012 to see if the debug CRT would catch the corruption. I was surprised to see that it didn't (calling `free()` instead of `realloc()` does notice the corruption).  I've opened a bug on connect.microsoft.com about that behavior - I think it's clear that the debug version of `realloc()` should have noticed the bad write.